# NSIS | Message Box | Displaying Text and Variable

Tags: nsis, messagebox

I am new to NSIS and I wanted to show a message with a text and a variable value (mainly for debugging purpose). Please let me know if this can be achieved by the following method

> Example: MessageBox MB_OK "Application Name" $VersionNumber

If this method is not correct please suggest an alternative.

Comment: It will work with the variable inside the quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MessageBox` string needs quotes (`"`, `'` or `) if it contains spaces.

```
!define COPYYEAR 2018

Var VersionNumber

Section
StrCpy $VersionNumber "1.2.3.4" ; You will probably read this from somewhere, not hardcode it
MessageBox MB_OK "Application Name $VersionNumber"
MessageBox MB_OK NoSpacesNoQuotesRequired$VersionNumber
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION "Copyright (R) ${COPYYEAR}"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are just wanting to display the 'OK' button, try this:

```
MessageBox MB_OK "Application Name= ${VersionNumber}"
```

References: [NSIS MessageBox](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/MessageBox) and [Chapter 2: Tutorial: The Basics](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter2.html)

Note: The entire message that is to be displayed, including any variables, must be encased in quotes.

Comment: That is a define, not a variable. Quotes are optional if there are no spaces